# How to add new version before updating the field values using Sitecore Powershell?

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

I have to update field values to a particular item. Instead of changing the item's final version, I would like to create a new version and do my updates. For ex: if en(v2) is the latest, I need to create en(v3) and update my changes.

Is there any PowerShell script to update this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below `PowerShell` script for create a new item version and update field value

```
# Get All items under particular node with specific template name
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path "master:/sitecore/content/Home" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.TemplateName -eq 'Template Name' }

# Loop all items 
foreach ($item in $items) 
{
    # Get item to update and create new item version 
   $itemToUpdate = Add-ItemVersion -ID $item.ID -Language en -IfExist Append
   $itemToUpdate.Editing.BeginEdit()
   $itemToUpdate.Fields["Button Text"].Value = "Button Text Mew"
   $itemToUpdate.Editing.EndEdit()
 
}
```

I tested it on my `Sitecore` instance and it's working as expected, please try it.

You can get more information about creating new item version from below `URL` as well.
https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/common/add-itemversion

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this approach.

```
# Create a new item version by providing item ID
$item = Add-ItemVersion -ID "{56305117-8C9C-4C08-96D5-BB97A8E27419}" -Language en -IfExist Append

# Update this new item version fields
$item.Editing.BeginEdit()
$item.Fields["test"].Value = "new version of item"
$item.Editing.EndEdit()
```

Hope this will help.

Thanks